# PERL - submit form containing token value

Tags: perl, user-agent, lwp

The page has the following input form

```
  <form name="action" method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="40f41b52643f1fdc" />
  </form>
```

input type="hidden" field is populated by the server.  I want to submit this form using Perl. So far I have the following Perl code

```
use LWP;
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new; 

my @req=('http://somesite.com/index.php', [action => 1,  token => ????, username => "john", password => "123456"]);
my $response = $ua->post(@req);

print  $response1->as_string();
```

but how can I get the value from `<input type="hidden" name="token" value="40f41b52643f1fdc" />`  and then submit it?

Comment: [perl is not an acronym](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a request to get the page with the form in it
2. Parse the HTML in the response using a tool like HTML::TreeBuilder
3. Search it for the input with the token
4. Copy it to a string
5. Use the code you have now.

Beware: The token is probably there as protection against CSRF attacks, so you will also need to save the cookies from the original response and use them in the subsequent response.

Alternatively, use a tool like WWW::Mechanize or Selenium and submit the form by virtually clicking the submit button instead of constructing the request manually.